# Full-page screenshot on Selenium v>=3.4.0?

Tags: selenium, screenshot, fullscreen

Selenium developers have decided to discontinue the full-page screenshot feature:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3912

What is the code necessary going forward, to emulate this feature in the application test scripts?

I tried to downgrade to Selenium 3.3.1, but there's some dependency on the driver and/or browser version which is not forward-compatible.

Comment: Try [ashot](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot)

Comment: Revised the question to add that I tried the obvious solution of downgrading to Selenium 3.3.1, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found in an obscure open-source library:

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SomeJavaTest.java**

```
private void screenshot(File out) throws IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

    final Screenshot screenshot = new AShot()
            .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100))
            .takeScreenshot(driver);

    final BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage();
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", out);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--headless'], 'binary': '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'}})
        self.driver.get('http://google.com/')

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

def test_screenshot(self):
    width = self.driver.execute_script(
        "return Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth);")
    height = self.driver.execute_script(
        "return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);")
    self.driver.set_window_size(width+100, height+100)
    self.driver.save_screenshot('screenshot ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) + '.png')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: this changes the browser size to an unrealistic size

Comment: but you will have a full page screenshot